# How can I move a theme directory to a remote with putty ftp?

Tags: wordpress, bash, unix, ftp

I tried this:

```
 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY

05/21/2015  12:00 AM    <DIR>          .
05/21/2015  12:00 AM    <DIR>          ..
05/21/2015  12:00 AM    <DIR>          sahifa
              14 File(s)      3,793,924 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  22,940,766,208 bytes free
psftp> put -r sahifa
/var/www/html/myblog/wp-content/themes/sahifa: create directory: permission deni
ed
psftp>
```

But it gave me a permission denied.

Here's the directories.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-160 wp-content]$ ls -al
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 4 nobody 65534 4096 May  7 01:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 nobody 65534 4096 May 19 06:47 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody 65534   28 Jan  8  2012 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 3 nobody 65534 4096 May  7 01:45 plugins
drwxr-xr-x 5 nobody 65534 4096 May  7 01:45 themes
```

I tried this but it does not seem to work:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-160 wp-content]$ [ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-160 wp-content]$ chmod 777 themes
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-160 wp-content]$ chmod: changing permissions of ‘themes’: Operation not permitted
```

I also tried this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 nobody 65534 4096 May  7 01:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 nobody 65534 4096 May 19 06:47 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody 65534   28 Jan  8  2012 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 3 nobody 65534 4096 May  7 01:45 plugins
drwxr-xr-x 5 nobody 65534 4096 May  7 01:45 themes
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-160 wp-content]$ chmod -v 746 themes
chmod: changing permissions of ‘themes’: Operation not permitted
failed to change mode of ‘themes’ from 0755 (rwxr-xr-x) to 0746 (rwxr--rw-)
```

Can someone give me some advice as to what I should be doing? Is the problem  maybe related to the fact that everything seems to be owned by "nobody" ?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current user `ec2-user` does not have permission to move or create files as current directory is owned by `nobody:65534`. If you have `sudo` access, put `sudo` at the beginning of your `chmod` command.

PS: `chmod 777` is never a good idea. You might want to check what is group `65534`, and add yourself to that group instead.